# Why do app posts to Facebook not show as pasted via my app, despite OK OpenGraph response?

Tags: facebook

We have an app on Facebook called TouchActive

We provide ways for user to post content to Facebook, either from web (via AddThis) or native Android/iOS app.

When we post from say Android we identify the app and the post appears correctly, showing "... via TouchActive" all fine.

When we post from web, we post a URL that Facebook queries, and we provide an OpenGraph response from our server with all the og: meta tags, including the facebook app_id.

The content appears correctly (it's parsing the OG response OK), but it doesn't show as posted via our app, and the posts don't appear in our Insight statistics for the app.

We are assuming this can be done.

Anyone know what we could be doing wrong in our open graph response that causes this to not work?

I have tried the Facebook debug tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it shows the correctly parsed OG response and no errors, only a warning about og:url.

Is og:url recommended or a MUST for this to work?

Comment: Can you show the graph url you are using to post from web?

Comment: Can you tell how you are posting through the app? via the JS-SDK or using a server side call? In either case, can you paste the relevant posting code? Also, can you link me to the page which has the AddThis installed? I believe I know the answer, but would like to validate before posting.

Comment: In the case that is failing we are posting a text that includes the url (example) "http://ta.bcntouch.com/p/".

Comment: Sorry, previous edit timed out...      In the case that is failing we are posting a text that includes the url (example) "http://ta.bcntouch.com/p/1756048". That causes the Facebook bot to do a request to that url and we reply with a page with OpenGraph markup that includes our appID (and has been validated correct using Facebook debugger). The behavior is the same whether posted manually by a human or via the AddThis widget we use also. I'd like that request to show as posted from our app and/or to show in our app's InSight statistics.

Comment: Note: To see the OpenGraph response from that URL, you will need to set your UserAgent to be the facebook bot.... a normal request will get the full html page "for humans".

Comment: Investigating more has raised questions about what Facebook is doing with the og:url field. It *seems* that if the og:url doesn't coincide with the url that FB fetched the OG data from it treats it like a re-direct and requests the OG data from that new URL, and so on until the og:url coincides (exactly?) with the url it was requested from. In some tests we got "too many redirect" errors from FB debugger as the og:url we returned didn't coincide 100% with the actual url it was requested from (due to encoding...), Could that be  the behavior and the cause of the problem do you think?

Comment: Whoever gives the best (confirmed) description of how facebook actually uses the og:url field will get the bounty within the next 24 hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew: I am also using the same meta tag for my site and it works as expected and the post is attributed to my site. I guess u should specify the og:url meta-tag once and then check. As this url is used on the attributed app's anchor link on fb wall.

If still it has the same issue then we can dig it more to come to solution.

Comment: Investigating more has raised questions about what Facebook is doing with the og:url field. It *seems* that if the og:url doesn't coincide with the url that FB fetched the OG data from it treats it like a re-direct and requests the OG data from that URL, and so on until the og:url coincides (exactly?) with the url it was requested from. In some tests we got "too many redirect" errors from FB debugger as the og:url we returned didn't coincide 100% with the actual url it was requested from (due to encoding...), Could that be  the behavior and the cause of the problem do you think?

Comment: Andrew: the URL of the page and the URL assigned to the og tag may not be same but they should hit the same page (as in case of URL rewrite). Also Encoding of url doesn't make them different. They are treated as same.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, this is what happens: If the og:url is different from the request url, facebook will make another request to the og:url (a kind of redirect viaOG response), and so on....until the og:url returned and url it made the request to resolve to the same value. FB must use code/libs to decode the og:url as it should be url encoded and maybe even XML escaped if inside XHTML?

Comment: Exactly :) Andrew I guess you should review the settings of your fb app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id/summary  and then check whether the fields(Namespace, Website and App on Facebook) are properly filled. You can also use this link to review your app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

A user manually sharing a link to or liking a web page which has opengraph meta tags (including an App ID) is not the same as posting the content from the app - are you definitely posting the links using the app?

You must post via the API to get the post attributed to your app, regardless of which app is specified on the page's meta tag (which is done primarily for insights and administration purposes)

Comment: I would like the post attributed to our app AND have the post show up in Insights. It seems at the moment that neither occur, so somehow the metatag is NOT causing the post to appear in Insights as you suggest should happen.

Comment: The meta tags [should] have no bearing on whether a post from your app is attributed as such and appear in the App's insights - how are you making the posts?

Comment: Charsee (see below) (I think) suggests the og:url meta-tag IS used to attribute to the app (although maybe "site" != "app")? Anyone got a reference to goo documentation on this? I have read the standard documentation and didn't find an explanation of these kind of details. Thanks.

Comment: How are you making the posts? if you're not making the posts via the app, the posts aren't attributed to the app - the like button uses the app_id tag to determine who can access the insights and admin option, but isn't used to show 'via APPname' on the like story

Comment: we are making the posts either manually (posting a url that has been associated with the app) or via AddThis. They both cause facebook to make a request to the url and we respond with opengraph markup that includes app_id and url....

Comment: That won't do it - you need to use your own app to make the post in order to have the post attributed to the app